# How to add a delete button in custom table in yii

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, yii

I have a form where I use ajaxSubmitButton to add product items in a HTML table. ajaxSubmitButton helps to use ajax to add item, ajax url take the values and update the table's body `<tr>`, `<td>`. In table, I want to keep a delete button in last column in every rows. When I click the delete button, a row should be deleted. But here delete button does not work. I have checked the hardcoded HTML table and jquery in views that works.

In this circumstance, how could I solve this issue. Please help me. I have given below the form and controller's code:

Form:

```
Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScript('removecartitem', "
$('#remove').click(function(){
$('#cartDetails tr:first').remove();
})
");
?>

<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-lg-2">
    <?php
    // this is the ajax submit button
    echo CHtml::ajaxSubmitButton('Add Item',Yii::app()->createUrl('admin/order/cart'),
        array(
            'type'=>'POST',
            'update'=>'#cartTable',
        ),
        array('class'=>'btn btn-primary btn-sm',));
    ?>
    </div>        
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
                <table id="cartDetails" class="table table-bordered sortableTable responsive-table">

                    <tbody id="cartTable"> // ajax updates this id 
                    </tbody>
                </table>

    </div>

</div>
```

In controller:

```
public function actionCart()
{
    if(isset($_POST["Order"])){            
    .....
    ..... 
    $cartDetails = Yii::app()->session['cart'];
    if(!empty($cartDetails)){
        foreach($cartDetails as $cart){
            echo '<tr>';
            echo '<td>'.$cart["product_id"].'</td>';
            echo '<td>'.$cart["product_name"].'</td>';
            echo '<td>'.$cart["product_code"].'</td>';
            echo '<td>'.$cart["quantity"].'</td>';
            echo '<td>'.$cart["price"].'</td>';
            echo '<td>'.$cart["totalPrice"].'</td>';
            echo '<td><input type="button" name="add" id="remove" value="Remove" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs"/></td>';
            echo '</tr>';

        }
    }

}
```

At this stage, none of jquery works. Please help how to enable jquery then how to activated the delete button. Please let me know if my explanation is not clear. I have added an images to explain more clear.

[image]

Comment: You can't put the same id to more than 1 element. Use a class 'remove' for example.

Comment: Yes I understand, I tried to use unique to check does jquery works or not. But jquery does not work once ajax updated HTML

Answer (score 0):

alter so you have a class for removal, for example

```
public function actionCart()
{
    if(isset($_POST["Order"])){            
    .....
    ..... 
    $cartDetails = Yii::app()->session['cart'];
    if(!empty($cartDetails)){
        foreach($cartDetails as $cart){
            .
            .
            .
            echo '<td>'.$cart["totalPrice"].'</td>'; // see below line , class : REMOVETHIS
            echo '<td><input type="button" name="doesntMatter" class="REMOVETHIS btn btn-danger btn-xs"/></td>';
            .

        }
    }

}
```

then on page ready, remove it on click

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.REMOVETHIS').click(function(){
        $(this).parent().parent().remove();
    });
});
```

UPDATE:

the code below will only remove first row of table,

```
$('#cartDetails tr:first').remove();
```

and I'm guessing even this wont work, because jquery needs to be used after document ready. like :

```
$(document).raady(function(){
    //put jquery related code in here
});
```

and like our friend said, you can NOT assign multiple elements with the same id, for that you better use classes,

and in this case because the row inserted to table is fresh, you need to state again

```
    $('.REMOVETHIS').click(function(){
        $(this).parent().parent().remove();
    });
```

after you have inserted the row, or you can do this:

```
 echo '<td><input type="button" name="doesntMatter" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" onclick="removeRow(this)"/></td>';
```

and when that element is clicked, removeRow function will be called

```
function removeRow(element)
{
    $(element).parent().parent().remove();
}
```

Comment: I did such things, I do not understand none of jquery works once getting the table from ajax updates.

Comment: thanks for your effort. Actually, my asking was different that js is not working rather handle with js code. I did it finally with lot of work.

Comment: lots of word, so write an answer, please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19811961/how-to-add-a-delete-button-in-custom-table-in-yii?answertab=active#tab-top. Thanks to ask

Answer (score 0):

As how I solve my problem:

I have an order from where I place order for registrants. In the order form, there are 3 fields i select registration, select product, then quantity. There is a ajaxSubmitButton what sends this value to the controller (actionCart). Controller saves the value i.e. product id, name, price, quantity, total price in session and update the ajax request in tabular format to the order form. During echoing `<tr>`, `<td>` I added a button to delete item from session. So, I want to delete value of session as well as the row of table once click button. But button did not work because jquery did not work although I saw that jquery was loaded.

I found that ajax updated HTML did not work with earlier loaded jquery. So I changed the strategy that separated Updated HTML table (what I echoed in controller) in another view file and used renderPartial into the controller. I injected my required Jquery snippets into the view file. Then I found that jquery is responding with ajax requested HTML tags.

Now I am working forward to unset the session array and row of table using jquery and ajax.